# Máscara de telefone brasileiro

Tags: ios, swift

Estou migrando do Android para o iOS agora, e estou com uma dúvida. 
Consigo fazer no Swift algo como `onTextChanged` do Java?

Eu preciso de uma *mask* pro meu `UITextField` que é dinâmico, de acordo com o numero de caracteres inseridos (`## ####-####` ou `## #####-####`).

Como consigo tratar isso no Swift 3?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a funcão textField shouldChangeCharactersIn range. Para isso, você precisa conectar o delegate do UITextField ao seu ViewController (seja pelo storyboard ou através de código), criar um outlet desse textField no código de seu ViewController, implementar o protocolo UITextFieldDelegate e utilizar o código como descrito abaixo. Ele vai lhe permitir a formatação para o número brasileiro já incluindo o quinto número após o código de área. Para deixar bem claro, abaixo onde utilizo "cellPhoneTextField", você deverá utilizar o nome do outlet do textField para o número de telefone que você tem conectado com o storyboard.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if textField == cellPhoneTextField {

        //New String and components
        let newStr = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
        let components = (newStr as NSString).components(separatedBy: NSCharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted)

        //Decimal string, length and leading
        let decimalString = components.joined(separator: "") as NSString
        let length = decimalString.length
        let hasLeadingOne = length > 0 && decimalString.character(at: 0) == (1 as unichar)

        //Checking the length
        if length == 0 || (length > 11 && !hasLeadingOne) || length > 13 {
            let newLength = (textField.text! as NSString).length + (string as NSString).length - range.length as Int

            return (newLength > 11) ? false : true
        }

        //Index and formatted string
        var index = 0 as Int
        let formattedString = NSMutableString()

        //Check if it has leading
        if hasLeadingOne {
            formattedString.append("1 ")
            index += 1
        }

        //Area Code
        if (length - index) > 2 {
            let areaCode = decimalString.substring(with: NSMakeRange(index, 2))
            formattedString.appendFormat("%@ ", areaCode)
            index += 2
        }

        if length - index > 5 {
            let prefix = decimalString.substring(with: NSMakeRange(index, 5))
            formattedString.appendFormat("%@-", prefix)
            index += 5
        }

        let remainder = decimalString.substring(from: index)
        formattedString.append(remainder)
        textField.text = formattedString as String
        return false

    } else {
        return true
    }

}
```

Comment: Opa, usando esse seu código é possível adaptar para algo do tipo: Caso o telefone seja com 8 digitos, o espaço ficar após o digito 4º e caso seja com 9 ficar após o 5º

Answer (score -2):

Para desenvolvimento **Swift** o melhor a se fazer para economizar tempo e linhas de código é usar **Frameworks**, coisa extremamente abundante no **iOS**.

Neste caso sugiro o uso do **TLCustomMask**, de fácil implementação usando PodFile.

Segue o framework do GitHub [TLCustomMask](https://github.com/Edudjr/TLCustomMask)